# How should I work around WinRT JS saying null is "null"?

Tags: c#, javascript, null, windows-runtime, projection

So I recently had a face-palm moment with Javascript and WinRT. Basically, I'm developing a WinRT API, so it should work well with Javascript, C++, and C#. I have a property in the API that does special stuff if the passed in value is null. So, for instance:

```
public string Foo
{
  get
  {
    return foobar.ToString();
  }
  set
  {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
      foobar=SomeSpecialValue;
      return;
    }
    ParseIntoFoobar(value);
  }
}
```

This seems like a perfectly fine property to me. However, when you use something like this from Javascript:

```
myFoobar.foo=null;
```

The result is a parsing exception thrown from `ParseIntoFoobar` Why? Because apparently the value of null in Javascript is `"null"` as in **a string containing the word null`**

From the documentation I've seen, this should result in either a conversion to null for C#, or it should result in an empty string, not this goofy result. In fact, you can make some really unintuitive behavior that makes no sense to me. Projection:

```
public string Biz{get;set;}
```

Javascript:

```
myObject.biz=null;
log(myObject.biz==null); //results in false
```

What is the best way to work around this "feature"? What should I do about things where I want to detect null, but where `"null"` as a string isn't exactly invalid? (think username or some such)

Comment: @bfavaretto well, in WinRT there isn't null strings. I'm ok with that. In C++ a null pointer passed in to a string argument will result in an empty string... but this isn't an empty string. It's probably the strangest thing I've seen Microsoft do to date

Comment: Couldn't it be `public string? Biz{get;set;}`?

Comment: @bfavaretto no because string is already a reference type, and there is no such thing as null in WinRT

Comment: Sorry, but I'm totally ignorant about WinRT. But Wikipedia says: "In WinRT, strings are immutable and null value is not allowed. If null value is passed to a string in WinRT by a language that has null semantics, the value is converted to empty string." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime#Restrictions_and_rules So it should be converted to `""`, not `"null"`...

Comment: @bfavaretto yes, that's my point.. but it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use empty string "" (string.Empty) which will be universally accepted.

My "guess" about why null isn't acceptable is probably because of some type mapping trickery that is happening to make everything compatible. C++ might be doing something weird like translating a null reference into a '\0' (null character), which would then be an empty string.

Comment: @Earlz - rather than the sloppy but widely used convention of null OR empty just standardize on the empty.

Comment: see http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-876T for statement that this is by design and (kind of) the reasoning behind it. It discusses this behavior at around 40 minutes